# Is it possible to covert outbound email messages to plain text ASA5550

Tags: email, cisco-asa

I have an old application that is using TLS 1.0 and am unable to upgrade. I would like to see if I can create an ACL to change from TLS 1.0 and forward on the email message as a plain text email to keep from being rejected by the email server filter?

I know this is an old firewall but, it's what I have to work with for now.